# Modify the x-axis label in chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to modify the `X-axis` of my scatter graph from `chart.js`. To do this, I just have to do as the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats) says.

But in my case, what I want to do, is replace the actual value (a number) with a word. The problem is that I don't know how to access to that words (they are in an array and they are in the correct order).

The array is like this:

```
words = ['Apple','Orange','Banana', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Lemon']
```

And my dataset is like:

```
datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset1',
    borderColor: '#FF0000',
    data: [{ x: 1, y: 88 }, { x: 2, y: 89 }, { x: 3, y: 86 }]
    }, {
    label: 'Dataset2',
    borderColor: '#00FF00',
    data: [{ x: 1, y: 88 }, { x: 2, y: 89 }, { x: 3, y: 86 }]
}]
```

xAxes label:

```
xAxes: [{
    type: 'linear',
    position: 'bottom',
    ticks: {
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
            console.log(words[index]);
            return '$' + value; //The $ is just to see some change
        }
    }
}]
```

I tried to use the index value, but it just return the last dataset index value. Another option is try to use the first value of the `array` and the delete this one just after.

How can I do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle showing the issue. I've setup this one which seems to work as expected https://jsfiddle.net/v8aLy9bm/

Answer (score 1):

I had to guess the semantics of your data but came up with following runnable code snippet. I hope this helps.

```js
const words = ['Apple','Orange','Banana', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Lemon'];

new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
    "type": "scatter",
    "data": {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset1',
            borderColor: '#FF0000',
            data: [{ x: 1, y: 88 }, { x: 2, y: 89 }, { x: 3, y: 86 }]
            }, {
            label: 'Dataset2',
            borderColor: '#00FF00',
            data: [{ x: 1, y: 65 }, { x: 2, y: 78 }, { x: 3, y: 33 }]
        }]
    },
    "options": {
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                ticks: {                    
                    callback: (value, index, values) => words[index],
                    stepSize: 1                    
                }
            }]
        }     
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```